# how to code in C# - the value in array is in which position ( eg: search value is 60, print - its in 6th postion of the array)

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

 namespace ConsoleApp1
{
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] numbers = new int[10] { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100 };

        int a = 60;
        bool searchvalue = false;

       for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {

            if (numbers[i] == a)
            {

                searchvalue = true;
               break;
            }
        }
        {
       }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The value a not found");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Store the index in another variable when you find the value.

Comment: first learn to format your code and post a proper question

Comment: your array is in sorted order and thus you can as well do a `binary search`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find index of an element in an array you can use `System.Array` like this:

```
int location = Array.IndexOf(numbers, a);
```

This returns the 0-based index of element `a` in `numbers` array which will be 5 in your example. Note that it will return `-1` in case the element isn't found. If you want the 1-based index as answer you should probably add 1 to the result:

```
int location = Array.IndexOf(numbers, a) + 1;
```

To do it without using `System.Array`:

```
int[] numbers = new int[10] { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100 };
int a = 60;
int result = -1;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (numbers[i] == a)
    {
        result = i;
        break;
    }
}
if (result != -1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("0-based location is " + result);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not found.");
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: don't think OP want tot use any library method for this purpose

Comment: @Rahul That's true. Updated to include the actual solution as well

Answer (score -2):

you can print 'i' with that. actually 60 is at 5th position.

Comment: Index 5 is the sixth index. Index 0 is the first, 1 is the second, 2 is the third, 3 is the fourth, 4 is the fifth, 5 is the sixth. `60` is at index 5 in a zero indexed array -- the sixth item in the array.

Comment: what about an increment to i? i mean i+1.

Comment: as we know array starts with index 0 and you want position that is starting from 1 : position=index+1 console,writeline(position);

Comment: Its index is `5`. If `position = index + 1;`, then `position` is equal to `6`, because `6` is one greater than `5`.

Comment: yeah exactly what i want to say!

Comment: Well, I'm glad we got that cleared up (he said, wracked by ghoulish laughter).